When and why did “orquestra” become “orquesta”?
While copyediting a concert program earlier today, I discovered that the Spanish word for “orchestra” is “orquesta,” not “orquestra.” The Diccionario de la lengua española lists “orquestra” as a “nombre desusado.”
When did this Spanish word lose its second “r,” and does anyone know why? Are there other examples of Spanish words that underwent a similar deletion?
According to Wiktionary, many languages‘ words for orchestra come from the Latin word “orchestra” (the area in front of a stage), which was borrowed from Greek ὀρχήστρα. Both Catalan and Portuguese use the word “orquestra,” with both r’s, as do all the descendants of the Latin word listed in Wiktionary, save Spanish.

Vas a ver esto muy seguido, a saber, que el español suele ser menos purista con la pronunciación. Bah, a mi juicio al menos, casi toda la pronunciación de las palabras heredadas del latín se simplificó mucho más en el español en comparación con las demás lenguas romances. Que, dicho sea de paso, no lo hace ni mejor ni peor, aunque sí un poco más peculiar. No me sorprendería ver que en un futuro no muy lejano nuestra pronunciación se vaya redondeando y suavizando cada vez más.
